# How do query subdocument from mongoid using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I have this document which I only want part of it. But I'm not sure how to do this in Mongoid query.

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5297d6773865640002000000"
},
"saved_tweets": [
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "52b0856b6535380002000000"
        },
        "saved_id": "123456",
        "tweet_ids": [
            "1",
            "2"
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "52b0856b6535380002000001"
        },
        "saved_id": "78901",
        "tweet_ids": [
            "3",
            "4"
        ]
    }
]}
```

What I want is all the tweet_ids according to the saved_id. This is what I'm doing right now which I think it's very ineffective.

```
existing_user = User.find_by(:social_id => social_id)
existing_user.saved_tweets.each do |saved_tweet| 
        if saved_id == saved_tweet.saved_id
            @saved_tweet_ids = saved_tweet.tweet_ids
        end
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try something like that?

```
user.saved_tweets.where(saved_id: user.saved_id).map(&:tweet_ids)
```

?